# How to reference a function in a different rake file

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I want to call a function that is in another rake file.

Rake File 1:

```
task :build => [:some_other_tasks] do
  foo
end

def foo(type = :debug)
  # ...
end
```

Rake File 2:

```
require_relative 'path_to_rake_file_1' 

task :foo2 => [:some_other_tasks] do
      foo
    end
```

I am currently getting a `no such file to load` error despite confirming the path is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining methods inside rake files and sharing them among rake tasks, it is best practice to create a `RakeHelper` module and include it in your rake file. So, you could have something like:

**rake_helper.rb**

```rb
module RakeHelper
  def self.foo
  end
end
```

**task1.rake**

```rb
include RakeHelper

task :build => [:some_other_tasks] do
  RakeHelper.foo
end
```

**task2.rake**

```rb
include RakeHelper

task :foo2 => [:some_other_tasks] do
  RakeHelper.foo
end
```